# Make derivative zero in Theano

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, theano, lstm

I am trying to implement LSTM optimizer from this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04474v1.pdf

They are making an assumption about derivative of gradient w.r.t. LSTM parameters equal to zero:

[image: picture]

Looking at my code I think that when I optimize loss function that assumption is not used because Theano can compute this gradient and it does so. How can I prevent it from doing this?

Here's the code:

```
def step_opt(cell_previous, hid_previous, theta_previous, *args):
    func = self.func(theta_previous)

    grad = theano.grad(func, theta_previous)
    input_n = grad.dimshuffle(0, 'x')

    cell, hid = step(input_n, cell_previous, hid_previous, *args) # function that recomputes LSTM hidden state and cell 

    theta = theta_previous + hid.dot(self.W_hidden_to_output).dimshuffle(0)
    return cell, hid, theta, func

cell_out, hid_out, theta_out, loss_out = theano.scan(
         fn=step_opt,
         outputs_info=[cell_init, hid_init, theta_init, None],
         non_sequences=non_seqs,
         n_steps=self.n_steps,
         strict=True)[0]

loss = loss_out.sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have found the answer. There is this page:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/gradient.html

We can use `disconnected_grad(expr)` to make backpropagation stop on `expr`.